# How to select word from textview and then change the font of that particular word at runtime

Tags: java, android

I am working on an android app in which a user can select a picture and after selecting picture user can add text over it as he wish. I am adding these textView as "I am taking a relative view and then adding a textView as a subview of this relative view". The relative view does contain the touch and pinch zoom listener to scale and rotate an image. Now the new requirements the user can select the select the text from textview and can change the selected word font and color . How can I do this?

Please help.